# Get count of variable by ID in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the below table:

```
ID  DS
------
1   IP  
1   IP  
1   OP  
1   OP  
2   IP  
2   OP  
2   IP  
2   OP  
2   IP  
3   OP  
3   IP  
3   OP  
4   OP  
5   OP  
5   IP  
5   OP
```

and I want this table returned:

```
ID  IP  OP
----------
1   2   2  
2   3   2  
3   1   2  
4   0   1  
5   1   2
```

How can I do this in T-SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query as below:

```
Select Id, Sum(case when DS = 'IP' then 1 else 0 end) as IP,
           Sum(case when DS = 'OP' then 1 else 0 end) as OP
   from yourtable
group by Id
```

Output as below:

```
+----+----+----+
| Id | IP | OP |
+----+----+----+
|  1 |  2 |  2 |
|  2 |  3 |  2 |
|  3 |  1 |  2 |
|  4 |  0 |  1 |
|  5 |  1 |  2 |
+----+----+----+
```